# nginx and trailing slashes on $document_root?

Tags: php, nginx, slash, trailing

I use the following configuration for nginx: http://gist.github.com/340956

However, this configuration causes a `No input file specified` error with PHP. The only way I have been able to solve it is by altering this line:

`fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;`

Note the "/" between `$document_root` and `$fastcgi_script_name`. I was informed that this is the wrong configuration but no one has been able to tell me exactly why my configuration requires this extra slash.

How can I get rid of that extra slash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just faced the same issue (in remi installation of nginx+php-fpm on a RHEL6 server), you can solve it by adding the following line in /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $request_filename;
```

I found this line missing in RHEL, while present in a perfectly working Debian nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Does the param `PATH_TRANSLATED` get the correct URI? I'm thinking it's the immediate concatenating of the variables in the conf file that doesn't compute. When adding a slash between them, maybe they are interpreted correctly.

When you get the error `No input file specified`, check your log to see what URI was requested.

Comment: What log should I check when I get a `No input file specified` error? nginx logs don't show anything, as the error is triggered by PHP.

Comment: There is no `PATH_TRANSLATED` in my `$_SERVER` dump.

Comment: The only thing that is logged by nginx is in the access log, and that just shows a "404" to any URL that uses rewriting.

Comment: The idea here is to find out what URI is requested

Answer (score 0):

Remove `try_files $uri index.php$uri;` in line 3.

Comment: Then my rewriting breaks, as I have URLs like `/foo/bar` which redirect to `index.php/foo/bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Matter of preference. As long as you are consistent, either way is fine.

Either add the slash in the configuration file, and ensure there are no additional slashes at the end and start of the document root and script name respectively or vice versa.

Comment: I don't buy it. It seems to make no difference whether I add a trailing slash to $root or not.

Answer (score 0):

what happens when you explicitly add a root directive like so:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    # fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    include fastcgi.conf;

    root /var/www/my_webroot;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

Comment: My `$root` is defined in `server { ... }` is that not good enough?